# Two clicks to get value of LI Item in jQuery - Should take 1

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery issue.

I have a HTML list setup as follows :

```
<ul class="areas">
 <li title="Volunteering">Volunteering</li>
 <li title="Partnership &amp; Support">Partnership &amp; Support</li>
 <li title="Business Services">Business Services</li>
</ul>
```

When the user clicks the outer div - styled select, I then filter through these items and add the title to a span.

The problem I have is, That it is taking two clicks for the "Volunteering" to appear in the span.

I have mocked up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/355Qk/) of this

My jQuery looks like this :

```
$('ul.areas').css('display', 'none');

$('.styled-select').click(function()
{
    var cur = $('.areas li.current');
    next = cur.next('li');

    var value = cur.attr('title');

    if (next.length === 0) {  // wrap if necessary
        next = $('.areas li:first');
    }

    cur.removeClass('current');  // move the current class
    next.addClass('current');

    $('.service-area').html(value);
})
```

How can I get it to work in just one click instead of two?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplify a bit:

```
$('.styled-select').click(function () {
    var cur = $('.areas li.current').length === 0 ? $('.areas li').eq(0) : $('.areas li.current').eq(0).removeClass('current');
    var next = cur.next('li').length ? cur.next('li').addClass('current') : cur.next('li').eq(0).addClass('current');
    var value = cur.attr('title');

    $('.service-area').html(value);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed your markup so that there is an `li` element with the `current` class and it seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/355Qk/1/

```
<ul class="areas">
    <li class="current" title="Volunteering">Volunteering</li>
    <li title="Partnership &amp; Support">Partnership &amp; Support</li>
    <li title="Business Services">Business Services</li>
</ul>
```

If that's not what you want to do then you could dynamically add the `current` class to the first `li` if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thank you @martincarlin87 that is exactly what I needed to do really. Works how I want it to aswell. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can get the tittle from the Next Element, curr is nothing when you first click it.

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/355Qk/3/

```
if (next.length === 0) {  // wrap if necessary
                next = $('.areas li:first');

            }

            var value = next.attr('title');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
var li = $('.areas li.current');
var cur = li.length ? li : $('.areas li:first').addClass('current');
next = cur.next('li');
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/355Qk/5/)